# PropertyChanged Fody accesses ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged, fody

Is it possible to instruct Fody to generate PropertyChanged Events for the Properties Color1
and Color2 if the corresponding Items in the ObservableCollection _colors are changing?

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Brush Color1 => _colors[0];
    public Brush Color2 => _colors[1];

    private ObservableCollection<Brush> _colors;

    public MyModel()
    {
        _colors = new ObservableCollection<Brush>()
        {
            Brushes.Transparent,
            Brushes.Black,
        };
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _colors[0] = Brushes.Green;
        _colors[1] = Brushes.Red;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

For the Name Property the Event will be generated, but not for Color1 and Color2 (see extract from ILSpy):

```
public string Name
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return <Name>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        if (!string.Equals(<Name>k__BackingField, value, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            <Name>k__BackingField = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(<>PropertyChangedEventArgs.Name);
        }
    }
}

public Brush Color1 => _colors[0];

public Brush Color2 => _colors[1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `Color1` and `Color2` are read-only properties, so there is no need generate `PropertyChanged` events for them. What you want is code to fire the event for property `A` when field `b` is set. I doubt that any code generator will do that (fields don't have setters, where the event needs to be invoked).

The `Fody` docs state that

> All classes that implement INotifyPropertyChanged will have notification code injected into property setters.

So, maybe your best try is to create properties with private setters (and remove your fields `_color1&2`).

Comment: Yes of course, set the properties directly will work, but the updates comes with an index so I have to code if (index == 1) Color1 = value; else if (index == 2) Color2 =  value; etc...